# How to scale a Texture in an Atlas without seeing neighbouring Textures

Tags: texturing

How can i control the image. I want to make the peanut in the bottle to be small. Increase or decrease in the uv layout the side texture mixing up. Anyway to make it small.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can change the scale value of your mapping node or go to the UV editor and scale the uv.

Comment: @NascentSpace when i scale in mapping node image beside also coming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remap the coordinates.

We benefit from the fact we know it is a Texture Atlas, with regular row and column sizes. Take the UV coordinates, check the local X and Y coordinates and remap it to the current Texture by adding it to the Start X and Y of the target Texture.

[image]

Result (With a scale of 6)

[image]

Unfortunately the individual textures are not seamless as it seems, so you will see Seams every time the UV snap back to the start coordinates.

Small helping addition **if you are using V 2.92**+. Create two custom properties in the object properties.

[image]

Instead of the Current Column and Row nodes, use Attribute nodes, set the type to Object, and type in the name of your attributes.

[image]

Now you can directly edit the Texture in the 3D Viewport :

[image]

Also, if you want to have a random Texture with each pot when you duplicate it :

Use the Random output from the Object Info node to randomize Atlas Position.

[image]

Result :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detail answer and the cool tips